# Create ToolStripMenuItem with checked items

Tags: c#, toolstrip, toolstripmenu

I need create one item in my ToolStripMenuItem with this feature: if I check it, in application is turn on "stay on top" property.

I tryed this code:

```
private void alwaysOnTopToolStripMenuItem_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (alwaysOnTopToolStripMenuItem.Checked)
            fForm1.TopMost = true;
        else
        {
            fForm1.TopMost = false;
        }
    }
```

but I get this error in Visual Studio 2010 (Windows Form)

[image]

I dont know how I can solve this strage issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like fForm1 isn't initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming the click handler lives in the form:

```
this.TopMost = alwaysOnTopToolStripMenuItem.Checked;
```